# Creating Scheduled Task from GPO without Password

Tags: windows, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a scheduled task in a Group Policy that runs a script that lives on the domain periodically.

I understand that storing the password in GP is a no no, so avoiding that. However, it seems like there is no way to deploy a scheduled task that can run with access to the network.

I tried the "System" account, that failed with access denied. I also tried using the "Do not store password" setting with a named account, which also prevents network access.

The scripts live in \domain\netlogon land and has full read access to authenticated users.

Is there anyway to accomplish this without having to manually install the task on every server and provide a named service account?

This is a Windows 2012 server domain with about 20 servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the "System" account to work correctly.